# Suppressed Exceptions in Java SE7

Tags: java, exception

I am trying to understand suppressed Exceptions in Java SE7, I posted 2 examples below, They are similar, In the following example, I was under the impression that when new "main Exception" happens, the suppressed ones get ignored, for instance I was expecting the output to be "java.lang.RuntimeException: y", However the answer is:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: y
suppressed java.lang.RuntimeException: a`

Here is the code:

```
class Animal implements AutoCloseable{

    @Override
    public void close() {
        throw new RuntimeException("a");   
    }
}

public class ExceptionsDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try(Animal a1 = new Animal();){
            foo();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
            for(Throwable t : e.getSuppressed()){
                System.err.println("suppressed "+ t);
            }
        }
    }

    static void foo() {
        try {
            throw new RuntimeException("x");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("y");
        }    
    }
}
```

My understanding was that after tryWithResources clause, "a" is main Exc, then in foo(), x becomes main exc while a gets suppressed, but in catch, I thought y will become the solo main exc and will ignore all other exceptions including suppressed ones?
 Like this second example, It does what I just mentioned, it outputs java.lang.RuntimeException: c  with no suppressed exceptions.

```
public class ExceptionDemo2 {

    class Animal implements AutoCloseable{

        @Override
        public void close() {
            throw new RuntimeException("a");   
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
           new ExceptionDemo2().go();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e);
            for(Throwable t : e.getSuppressed()){
                System.err.println("suppressed "+ t);
            }
        }
    }

    void go(){
        try(Animal a = new Animal()){
            throw new IOException();
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw new RuntimeException("c");
        }
    }

}
```

output: `java.lang.RuntimeException: c`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example

```
try(Animal a1 = new Animal();){
    foo();
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println(e);
    for(Throwable t : e.getSuppressed()){
        System.err.println("suppressed "+ t);
    }
}
```

terminates because `foo()` throws a `RuntimeException` (`y`). That's the target of the `catch`. Because execution leaves the `try` block, all declared resources are closed. While closing the `Animal` instance, another `RuntimeException` (`a`) is thrown. That one is suppressed because it wasn't the root cause.

The translation of `try-with-resources` to a `try-catch-finally` block is explained in the JLS, [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1).

> The meaning of a basic try-with-resources statement:
>
> ```
> try ({VariableModifier} R Identifier = Expression ...)
>     Block
> ```
>
> is given by the following translation to a local variable declaration
>   and a try-catch-finally statement:
>
> ```
> {
>     final {VariableModifierNoFinal} R Identifier = Expression;
>     Throwable #primaryExc = null;
>
>     try ResourceSpecification_tail
>         Block
>     catch (Throwable #t) {
>         #primaryExc = #t;
>         throw #t;
>     } finally {
>         if (Identifier != null) {
>             if (#primaryExc != null) {
>                 try {
>                     Identifier.close();
>                 } catch (Throwable #suppressedExc) {
>                     #primaryExc.addSuppressed(#suppressedExc);
>                 }
>             } else {
>                 Identifier.close();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

where

> If the resource specification declares one resource, then
>   `ResourceSpecification_tail` is empty (and the try-catch-finally
>   statement is not itself a try-with-resources statement).

Your code above basically translates to something like

```
try {
    final Animal a1 = new Animal();
    Throwable thr = null;
    try {
        foo();
    } catch (Throwable root) {
        thr = root;
        throw root;
    } finally {
        if (a1 != null) {
            if (thr != null) {
                try {
                    a1.close();
                } catch (Throwable suppressed) {
                    thr.addSuppressed(suppressed); // <<<<<< suppressing the failure of 'close'
                }
            } else {
                a1.close();
            }
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println(e);
    for (Throwable t : e.getSuppressed()) {
        System.err.println("suppressed " + t);
    }
}
```

Comment: So in the second example in the go() function, There is IOException and suppressed "a" exception, then it executes the new runtime Exception "c", why does it throw away the suppressed "a"?

Comment: @user1529412 It's not doing that, you are. You're explicitly ignoring the exception you caught, `e` (which has the suppressed exceptions), and throwing an entirely new exception, `c`. That exception is unrelated to the `try-with-resources` statement.

Answer (score 2):

This is confusing because it mixes try-with-resources with the exception-masking behavior that try-with-resources is supposed to cure.

Also it seems like you're not aware of what it means for an exception to be suppressed. Suppressed means that the exception is tacked on to an existing exception, rather than being thrown, and in the progress causing the exception thrown within the try-block getting lost (the usual term is "masked").

Exception-masking means that an exception thrown from the finally or catch block results in any exception thrown from within the try block getting discarded. Since the exceptions thrown on in the try-blocks are usually descriptive of what your error is, and the exceptions thrown on close are usually uninteresting, this is a bad thing; try-with-resources was created in order to try to reduce the prevalence of this problem.

So in your first example, foo is called on a1 within the try block, within foo the exception thrown within the catch, y, masks the exception thrown in foo's try block. Then when the try-with-resources block is exited the close method is called and the exception thrown on close gets added onto the y exception that is in-flight. So your printlns show y, then iterate through the suppressed exceptions attached to y.

In the second example, c is what's thrown from the go method (it's the same masking behavior described above). The IOException in the go method try block got thrown, the close method was called on the way out, causing the exception on close to get added to the IOException as a suppressed exception, then the IOException gets masked by c. Because a got masked, and the suppressed exception was attached to a, we lose the suppressed exception too. The c exception thrown on close has no suppressed exceptions associated with it because it was generated after the try-with-resources block was exited.

Comment: Let's say I remove the line throw new RuntimeException("c"); That means I would still have IOException with "a" attached, Why does the code print nothing then?

Comment: @user1529412: if all you do is remove the line with the `throw new RuntimeException("c");`, then the catch is still there. you ate the exception, it disappears without a trace.

Comment: Ok yes it makes sense. I understand it now, I made the example confusing because I am studying for Java Certificate thing, they tend to do similar confusing problems.

Comment: @user1529412: it's good to understand this sort of thing, it comes in handy in the real world.

Answer (score 0):

From the Oracle documentation http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html:

If an exception is thrown from the try block and one or more exceptions are thrown from the try-with-resources statement, then those exceptions thrown from the try-with-resources statement are suppressed. You can retrieve these suppressed exceptions by calling the Throwable.getSuppressed method from the exception thrown by the try block.

So as expected the first example gives the output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: y
suppressed java.lang.RuntimeException: a
```

In the second code snippet also there is a case of Exception Suppression. To validate that I have modified your function as:

```
void go() {
        try (Animal a = new Animal()) {
            throw new IOException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            for (Throwable t : e.getSuppressed()) {
                System.err.println("suppressed " + t);
            }
            throw new RuntimeException("c");            
        }
    }
```

Then the output will be:

```
suppressed java.lang.RuntimeException: a
java.lang.RuntimeException: c
```